# Android: Change View size between relative and absolute definitions

Tags: android

I'm trying to change a view's width programmatically, toggling between "fit width" (match_parent in the XML definition) and "fixed width" (320dp in the XML)

I couldn't find a way to programmatically set the view width to match_parent and leave Android compute everything for me. What would be the best solution to get that feature working?

```
if(ratio.equals("square")) {
    view.getLayoutParams().width = view.getHeight();
} else {
    // Set view width to match_parent
}
```

Thanks!

Answer (score -1):

I found a solution:

```
    view.getLayoutParams().width = ViewGroup.LayoutParams.MATCH_PARENT;
```

I don't really understand why it's in ViewGroup but it works!